# Show the correct tabs when Bootstrap Modal is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have three buttons in my homepage and a modal with three tabs. I want to fire up the correct tab when the respective buttons are clicked. How should I go about it?

For example: I want to show the "Careers" tab if the Careers button is clicked. Likewise, the same for Contact & Partners too.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="btn btn-primary">Contact</span></a></div>
<div class="col-xs-4"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="btn btn-primary">Careers</span></a></div>
<div class="col-xs-4"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="btn btn-primary">Partners</span></a></div>
</div>

<!-- modal-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <a href="" class="pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</a>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="contact" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <h3>Contact Form</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="careers" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Careers Form</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="partners" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Partners Form</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/47uj5gwe/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `data-target-tab="#contact"` with correct tab name on each of you buttons. And on `show.bs.modal` ([bootstrap modal events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)), open the correct tab ([bootstrap tab methods](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-methods)).

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
  $("a[href='"+button.data('target-tab')+"']").tab('show');
})
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47uj5gwe/1/)

Comment: So awesome. Thank you :)